# Does gsutil rsync incur additional charges for Google Cloud Storage Coldline buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, cloud-storage

I need to do a large upload ~1.5TB to Google Cloud Storage coldline. I was intending on using gsutil's rsync command. But I have a concern. Will the checksum validation of rsync incur additional charges per object in a Coldline bucket. I have tried to ascertain this but cannot find the information anywhere. If anyone else had experienced this, I'd appreciate the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash validation is included at the [end of the copy operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_Validation). It is also documented that you will be charge by the type of operation. The copy operation is a [Class A operation.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class)

So, no. There will be no further charges on the checksum validation **if it is made by server side at the end of the copy command** because you were already charged for the operation of copy.

If you decide to do it [yourself](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_Validation), well, you will have to download metadata and this could incur in more operations.

Still, take a look at the pricing page of Cloud Storage, you may also be charged for Retrieval and early deletion of [Nearline and Coldline](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#archival-pricing).